# Beautiful Soup Table to CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to try and scrape a website table and extract only specific columns to a CSV file.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product_table = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(product_table, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('table')[4]

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

the `print(row)` outputs:

```
[]
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', 'Albanese Confectionery Group', 'Gummi Sour Bears 12 Flavor', '12', '7 oz', '17.14', 'CS', '53328', '', 'ACG53328', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', 'Albanese Confectionery Group', 'Gummi Bears 12 Flavor', '12', '7.5 oz', '17.14', 'CS', '53348', '', 'ACG53348', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', 'Albanese Confectionery Group', 'Gummi Mini Worms 12 Flavor', '12', '7.5 oz', '17.14', 'CS', '53350', '', 'ACG53350', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', "Albanese World's Best", 'Gummi Bears 12 Flavor', '6', '9 oz', '11.59', 'CS', '53380', '', 'ACG53380', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', "Albanese World's Best", 'Gummi Mini Worms 12 Flavor', '6', '9 oz', '11.59', 'CS', '53381', '', 'ACG53381', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', "Albanese World's Best", 'Peach Rings', '6', '8 oz', '11.59', 'CS', '53383', '', 'ACG53383', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', "Albanese World's Best", 'Gummi Worms Mini Sour Neon', '6', '8 oz', '11.59', 'CS', '53384', '', 'ACG53384', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', "Albanese World's Best", 'Gummi Bears 12 Flavor', '12', '3.5 oz', '8.23', 'CS', '53450', '', 'ACG53450', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'ALBANESE CONFEC', "Albanese World's Best", 'Gummi Sherbet Bears 12 Flavor', '12', '3.5 oz', '8.23', 'CS', '53456', '', 'ACG53456', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
['', 'CANDY', 'AMERICAN LICORI', 'Red Vines', 'Red Vines Orig Red Twists Bag', '12', '8 oz', '19.20', 'CS', '00232', '', 'AML00232', '', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0']
```

So my question is: How to I extract only cells `[11]` and `[7]` from each row and print all of them side by side to a csv. So example for row 1 I want to write ACG53328(Cells A) and 17.14 (Cells B) to a csv file and continue downward. There are around 4,000 additional lines that I didn't paste here if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try this `td_12 = tr.find_all('td')[12].text : td_08 = tr.find_all('td')[8].text`.

Comment: where should I try this? I entered this into the print function and it says invalid syntax. doing print(row[11], row[7]) gives me the data I am looking for but it only pulls cells from the bottom row in this list. I also need to turn these into a csv.

Comment: what's the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
import csv
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product_table = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(product_table,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[4]
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['SKU', 'TD_7'])
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        try:
            td_12 = tr.find_all('td')[12].get_text(strip=True)
        except IndexError:
            td_12 = ""
        try:
            td_08 = tr.find_all('td')[8].get_text(strip=True)
        except IndexError:
            td_08 = ""
        writer.writerow([td_12, td_08])
```

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-508-7724d95dc202> in <module>
      4     writer = csv.writer(f)
      5     for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
----> 6         td_12 = tr.find_all('td')[11].get_text(strip=True)
      7         td_08 = tr.find_all('td')[7].get_text(strip=True)
      8         writer.writerow([td_12, td_08])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Check out the edit. It's difficult to offer any solution without the link.

Comment: You did it, great job! I really appreciate the help. I will research the pieces you gave me so I can understand it better. I only changed td to [11] and [7] to get the cells I needed because 0=1.  Would it be possible to make the header above TD_11 'SKU' and TD_7 'Case Price'?

Comment: It's done. Check out the update and make sure to press the greyed out tick mark right next to my answer if it helped you solve the issue. Thanks.