# Creating a CSV File from a Wikipedia table using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to scrape the **first 3 Columns** from a table in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_winners_and_shortlisted_authors_of_the_Booker_Prize) Wikipedia Page.

I implemented the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513615/how-can-i-extract-a-table-from-wikipedia-using-beautiful-soup).

```
import requests
import lxml
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#requesting the page
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_winners_and_shortlisted_authors_of_the_Booker_Prize'
page = requests.get(url).text 

#parsing the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

#selecting the table that matches the given class
table = soup.find('table',class_="sortable wikitable")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = pd.concat(df)
print(df)
df.to_csv("booker.csv", index = False)
```

It worked like a charm. Gave me exactly the output I was looking for:

[Expected Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1NJX.png)

However, the solution above uses pandas.

I want to create the same output without using pandas.

I referred to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018724/beautiful-soup-table-to-csv) but the output I am getting looks like this:

[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxTne.png)

here is the code that generates "Output 2":

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#requesting the page
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_winners_and_shortlisted_authors_of_the_Booker_Prize'
page = requests.get(url).text 

#parsing the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

#selecting the table that matches the given class
table = soup.find('table',class_="sortable wikitable")

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Year','Author','Title'])
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        try:
            td_1 = tr.find_all('td')[0].get_text(strip=True)
        except IndexError:
            td_1 = ""
        try:
            td_2 = tr.find_all('td')[1].get_text(strip=True)
        except IndexError:
            td_2 = ""
        try:
            td_3 = tr.find_all('td')[3].get_text(strip=True)
        except IndexError:
            td_3 = ""
        writer.writerow([td_1, td_2,td_3])
```

So my question is: How do I get the expected output without using Pandas?

P.S: I've tried to parse the rows in the table like this:

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#requesting the page
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_winners_and_shortlisted_authors_of_the_Booker_Prize'
page = requests.get(url).text 

#parsing the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

#selecting the table that matches the given class
table = soup.find('table',class_="sortable wikitable")

rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cell = row.td
    if cell is not None:
        print(cell.get_text())
        print(cell.next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text())
    else:
        print("heehee")
```

But the output I get looks like this:

```
heehee
1969
Barry England
Nicholas Mosley
Iris Murdoch
Muriel Spark
Gordon Williams
1970
A. L. Barker
Elizabeth Bowen
Iris Murdoch
William Trevor
Terence Wheeler
1970   Awarded in 2010 as the  Lost Man Booker Prize[a]
Nina Bawden
Shirley Hazzard
Mary Renault
Muriel Spark
Patrick White
1971
Thomas Kilroy
Doris Lessing
Mordecai Richler
Derek Robinson
Elizabeth Taylor
1972
Susan Hill
Thomas Keneally
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get your desired results from there. Make sure your bs4 version is up to date or at least higher than `4.7.0` for it to support pseudo css selector which I've used within the script.

```
import csv
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_winners_and_shortlisted_authors_of_the_Booker_Prize'

page = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Year','Author','Title'])
    for row in soup.select('table.wikitable > tbody > tr')[1:]:
        try:
            year = row.select_one("td[rowspan]").get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError: year = ""
        try:
            author = row.select_one("td:not([rowspan]) > a[title]").get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError: author = ""
        try:
            title = row.select_one("td > i > a[title], td > i").get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError: title = ""
        writer.writerow([year,author,title])
        print(year,author,title)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `pandas` directly:

```py
import pandas as pd


url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_winners_and_shortlisted_authors_of_the_Booker_Prize"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0][["Year", "Author", "Title"]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                  Year                Author                                        Title
0                                                 1969           P. H. Newby                      Something to Answer For
1                                                 1969         Barry England                       Figures in a Landscape
2                                                 1969       Nicholas Mosley                        The Impossible Object
3                                                 1969          Iris Murdoch                        The Nice and the Good
4                                                 1969          Muriel Spark                             The Public Image
5                                                 1969       Gordon Williams                       From Scenes Like These
6                                                 1970        Bernice Rubens                           The Elected Member
7                                                 1970          A. L. Barker                            John Brown's Body
8                                                 1970       Elizabeth Bowen                                    Eva Trout
9                                                 1970          Iris Murdoch                                Bruno's Dream
10                                                1970        William Trevor               Mrs Eckdorf in O'Neill's Hotel
11                                                1970       Terence Wheeler                              The Conjunction
12   1970 Awarded in 2010 as the Lost Man Booker Pr...         J. G. Farrell                                     Troubles
13   1970 Awarded in 2010 as the Lost Man Booker Pr...           Nina Bawden                       The Birds on the Trees
14   1970 Awarded in 2010 as the Lost Man Booker Pr...       Shirley Hazzard                              The Bay of Noon
15   1970 Awarded in 2010 as the Lost Man Booker Pr...          Mary Renault                             Fire From Heaven
16   1970 Awarded in 2010 as the Lost Man Booker Pr...          Muriel Spark                            The Driver's Seat
17   1970 Awarded in 2010 as the Lost Man Booker Pr...         Patrick White                               The Vivisector

...
```

---

To CSV:

```py
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)
```

Creates `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. I'd asked for a solution without using Pandas, but this is a valid soution.